# SQL concat with columns name

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I would like to do a SQL request like this :

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title
FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts AS p
INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta pm
ON pm.post_id=p.ID AND pm.meta_key='shops_list'
INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."follow AS f
ON pm.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%',f.shop_followed_id,'%')
```

`shop_followed_id` is the column name it doesn't work, but when I test with `CONCAT('%',163,'%')`, it worked.

Do you know where is the syntax error?

exemple of meta_value : a:3:{i:0;s:3:"168";i:1;s:2:"22";i:2;s:2:"43";}
exemple of shop_followed_id : 168

Comment: *It doesn't work* can you replace this with the original error message in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to me you got the like backwards. try:

```
INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."follow AS f
ON f.shop_followed_id LIKE CONCAT('%',pm.meta_value,'%')
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's really pm.meta_value LIKE CONCAT('%',f.shop_followed_id,'%')that i'm searching.

exemple of meta_value : a:3:{i:0;s:3:"168";i:1;s:2:"22";i:2;s:2:"43";}
exemple of shop_followed_id : 168

Comment: Problem is the condition. Did you try something like this instead: 
inner join table as f on Locate(f.shop_followed_id, pm.meta_value) > 0
?

Answer (score 0):

Use Casting for the f.shop_followed_id.

CONCAT('%',CAST(f.shop_followed_id As VARCHAR),'%')

May be this work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title AS title, p.post_type AS post_type, p.post_date AS post_date, f.id_shop_followed, pm.meta_value
            FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."posts AS p
            INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta pm
            ON pm.post_id=p.ID AND pm.meta_key='shops_list'
            INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."follow AS f
            ON f.id_user_following = $id_user AND LOCATE(f.id_shop_followed, pm.meta_value)>0  AND f.id_shop_followed > 0
            WHERE ( p.post_type='news' OR p.post_type='promotions' OR p.post_type='product')
                AND p.post_status='publish' AND f.id_user_following = $id_user
            GROUP BY p.ID
```

Thank you very much Tuncay Göncüoğlu
@Brahmanand Choudhary : I didn't try your solution but it perhaps works